# Adding a non-blocking delayed event to a request in sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, server-sent-events

I'm playing around with the chat client example that demonstrates streams and server side events in sinatra (see https://gist.github.com/rkh/1476463). Note that this has to be tweaked to work with modern jquery. Specifically:

```
// writing
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(e) {
```

And I got to toying with the idea of what if I wanted the broadcast to happen after some delayed period of time. I can do the naive thing and modify the post response with a sleep:

```
 post '/' do
   sleep 20
   settings.connections.each { |out| out << "data: #{params[:msg]}\n\n" }
   204 # response without entity body
 end
```

But then the 204 isn't actually sent until after the 20 second sleep has finished, which is silly. Plus this seems to break after 5 delayed messages comes in. Then no further posts are received until those 5 finish their sleep.

Comment: Have you tried doing it inside a `Thread.new do ...`?